# Herencia en controller.php Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, herencia

¿Es posible crear una función en el archivo Controller.php y luego utilizarla en los controllers?
Trato de hacerlo y me aparece el error:

```
Method [findArticleById] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController].
```

La function en Controller.php:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    private function findArticleById($id)
    {
      return Article::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

El controller:

```
public function show($id)
  {
    $article = $this->findArticleById($id);

    addVisitCountToArticle($article);

    return view('articles.item.show', compact('article'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

El segundo controller debería extender el primero tal y como el primero extiende BaseController.

El segundo quedaría así (*):

```
class SegundoController extends Controller
   {
       public function show($id)
          {
            $article = $this->findArticleById($id);

            addVisitCountToArticle($article);

            return view('articles.item.show', compact('article'));
          }
   }
```

(*) Me invento nombres de `classe` ya que no la pones. No hago mención al namespace aunque se debería tener en cuenta. No olvidar importar la classe Controller